# issue to modify an object value in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code.

```
var emp={"EmployeeLists":[{"ID":1,"NAME":"Anbu","Salary":80000},{"ID":2,"NAME":"Anand","Salary":90000}]};

// Inserting a new object into EmployeeLists
emp.EmployeeLists.splice(2,0,emp.EmployeeLists[1])
console.log(JSON.stringify(emp));
```

**Output:** `{"EmployeeLists":[{"ID":1,"NAME":"Anbu","Salary":80000},{"ID":2,"NAME":"Anand","Salary":90000},{"ID":2,"NAME":"Anand","Salary":90000}]}`

```
// Modifying inserted object NAME Anand into MANI
emp.EmployeeLists[2].NAME="MANI";
console.log(JSON.stringify(emp));
```

**Output:** `{"EmployeeLists":[{"ID":1,"NAME":"Anbu","Salary":80000},{"ID":2,"NAME":"**MANI**","Salary":90000},{"ID":2,"NAME":"**MANI**","Salary":90000}]}`

After added a new object. I tried to modify the name of that object **Anand** to **MANI** but it is modified name of object **Two** and **Three**.

Comment: Your question is unclear, can you explain exactly what you want to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question! What you are seeing is underlying sharing of objects, because Javascript secretly treats objects like pointers in C if you are not careful. Let's rewrite this to make a clone of the object instead. We will use [this previous Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/most-elegant-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object) (cloning objects in Javascript is annoying to do in full generality).

```
function clone(obj) {
    if (null == obj || "object" != typeof obj) return obj;
    var copy = obj.constructor();
    for (var attr in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(attr)) copy[attr] = obj[attr];
    }
    return copy;
}

emp.EmployeeLists.splice(2, 0, clone(emp.EmployeeLists[1]));
emp.EmployeeLists[2].NAME = "MANI";
// {"EmployeeLists":[{"ID":1,"NAME":"Anbu","Salary":80000},{"ID":2,"NAME":"Anand","Salary":90000},{"ID":2,"NAME":"MANI","Salary":90000}]}
```